# Where is the JDK in TravisCI?

Tags: java, travis-ci

When starting a TravisCI build I get:

```
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
```

I need `JAVA_HOME` to point to the JDK instead. Can I do this somehow?

These are the only Java related lines in my `.travis.yml`:

```
language: java
jdk:
  - oraclejdk8
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JDK is at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle

You could do:

```
before_install:
    - export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
```